# Avogadro2 does not label atom properly

Tags: macos, avogadro

I am new to Avogadro2 and I tried to explore it by myself. I was trying the 'atom label tool' and I tried to label one atom randomly, but as I press keys on my keyboard, chinese characters appeared. I don't know how to fix it. it seems like that it does not recognise the input keyboard properly. I am currently work on a macOS Sonoma 14.3 and the Avogadro2 release is the 1.98.1, the system language is English as the Avogadro app.

in any case my keyboard works fine in other apps and in the system in general...so it must be something wrong with Avogadro.

I tried to change the language of the app but it does not work. I have no clue on why is doing this.

Comment: Have you checked the installation process? Or is this a "copy" downloaded form somewhere and the language set by the original install? If you bought the software new then check with the supplier as you have a warranty.

Comment: @SolarMike - Avogadro is an open source chemistry program, and based on the comments, OP installed directly from GitHub or https://two.avogadro.cc/

Comment: Please submit a bug report either to https://discuss.avogadro.cc/ or on GitHub. I haven't used the atom label tool much, but I'll look into it. BTW, this is probably better suited for https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @GeoffHutchison Which comments state that the OP installed directly from Github? Or is that YOUR assumption?

Comment: @SolarMike I downloaded the .dmg file from two.avogadro.cc I don't know maybe I had to download the nightly build instead? I had a look to see if someone else had my same problem but it seems just me...

Comment: @SolarMike - I'm the lead developer, which is why I follow this tag. OP installed the latest version, which is currently only available through GitHub or linked on our site (which downloads via GitHub). Moreover, OP found a bug, which now has a fix for the next nightly build. There's no language set on install, no purchase, and no warranty as an open source program.